# Mostrar reporte pdf (JSP, JasperReport)

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

lo que busco es escribir en `input` , el dia y según eso, al dar click en un boton que me redirija a otro `.jsp` y mostrar solo reportes de ese día.

calculo.jsp

```
<form action="reportepdf.jsp" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div class="col-5">

    <input class="input-xlarge" name="anioReporte" />
</div>

<div class="col-5">
    <input type="submit" class="btn">Realizar</button>
</div>
  </form>
```

al dar click en el boton, me redirige a la página reporte.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page import="model.Conexion"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@page import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>JSP Page</title>
   </head>
  <body>

    <%
        File jasperFile = new File(application.getRealPath("reportes/report1.jasper"));
        Map<String, Object> parametro = new HashMap();

        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(jasperFile.getPath(), parametro,
                Conexion.getConnection());

        String txtFecha = request.getParameter("anioReporte");
        parametro.put("anio", txtFecha);
        
      response.setContentType("application/pdf");
      response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
      response.getOutputStream().write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
      response.getOutputStream().flush();
      response.getOutputStream().close();

        
    %>
</body>
```

Este sería el parametro que coloqué para que lo lea en el jsp:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno, me muestra el PDF pero vacio y con esta excepcion:

```
StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:735)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:221)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.initOut(JspWriterImpl.java:195)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.flushBuffer(JspWriterImpl.java:188)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.release(PageContextImpl.java:240)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalReleasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:185)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.releasePageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:137)
  at org.apache.jsp.reportepdf_jsp._jspService(reportepdf_jsp.java:99)
  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
|#]
```

Lo que he podido averiguar es que solo se debe tener ejecutado bien `getWriter()` o `getOutputStream()`

Pero no veo que ejecute el primero, he estado investigando mucho y no doy con la solución, además me debería de mostrar los reportes correctos, ya que estoy colocando el dia correcto. Espero me puedan ayudar por favor, muchas gracias

Comment: Estoy un poco oxidado en el tema pero el servidor genera un servlet a partir de la página JSP y para remitir la página generada ya establece en su response un content-type y escribe en el outputStream, lo cual entra en conflicto con lo que tú quieres hacer. Una posible solución es programar tú directamente el servlet que genera el informe. Sin JSP. Aquí tienes una pista de como hacerlo https://stackoverflow.com/a/50459219/2553194

Comment: Intenta colocar tu variable txtFecha y el parametro.put antes de tu arreglo de bytes.